# JSON Array Construction PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

I have part of a JSON feed that I need to segment based on variable existance, but its a nested array and I am not quite sure how to write it down.

Here is the code

```
        $postData += array(
        'LineItems' => array(
            array(
                'ItemName' => $_POST['milestone_1_detail'],
                'Description' => 'Minimum Guarantee - Installment 1',
                'Quantity' => 1,
                'Price' => $_POST['milestone_1_amount'],
                'SellComm' => 0,
                'BuyComm' => 0,
                'Accept' => true
            ),
            array(
                'ItemName' => $_POST['milestone_2_detail'],
                'Description' => 'Minimum Guarantee - Installment 2',
                'Quantity' => 1,
                'Price' => $_POST['milestone_2_amount'],
                'SellComm' => 0,
                'BuyComm' => 0,
                'Accept' => true
            ),
            array(
                'ItemName' => $_POST['milestone_3_detail'],
                'Description' => 'Minimum Guarantee - Installment 3',
                'Quantity' => 1,
                'Price' => $_POST['milestone_3_amount'],
                'SellComm' => 0,
                'BuyComm' => 0,
                'Accept' => true
            )
        )
    );
```

As you can see, its three (potentially) items all listed in a parent array

I need to do a basic

```
if ($_POST['milestone_1_amount']) { LineItem1 }
if ($_POST['milestone_2_amount']) { LineItem2 }
if ($_POST['milestone_3_amount']) { LineItem3 }
```

type condition for all three items,that will still keep those child arrays in the parent array but ONLY show the lineItems that have a value set, but not quite sure how to correctly write the code and retain the array format

Thank you in advance for helping me to stop tearing my hair out

Comment: I do, but again, I am not sure how to keep the array structure intact with the child elements